# Graphical Modeler location of saved models

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Is there any way to change the default location of the saved models in Graphical Modeler? (QGIS 3.16)

Comment: The correct answer to this question is: Yes.

Comment: The helpful answer is: Settings - Processing - Models. Can't check the translation, since QGIS doc seems to be down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Settings - Options - Processing
[image]